# Images not responsive although in responsive container

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have the following:

```
<div id="hp_imgs">
    <img src="/images/hp/1.jpg">
    <img src="/images/hp/2.jpg">
    <img src="/images/hp/3.jpg">
    <img src="/images/hp/4.jpg">
    <img src="/images/hp/5.jpg">
    <img src="/images/hp/6.jpg">
    <img src="/images/hp/7.jpg">
    <img src="/images/hp/8.jpg">
</div>
```

The images were sized when created to form a grid of sorts, so need to be in the order where they are.

Consequently, when/if the page is resized I want the images to resize and stay where they are.

Here's what I'm trying but images are simply staying the same size and not resizing:

```
#hp_imgs {
    width:66%;
    float:left;
}

#hp_imgs img {
    float:left;
    margin:2px;
    border-radius:4px;
    display: block;
    max-width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Is there a better/different way to achieve this?

**FIDDLE**

Here's a sample to play with: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darrensw/C8gYC/)

**JSBin**

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ilavum/1/edit)

Comment: do you have a fiddle ?

Comment: A fiddle with your attempt would be great - to have something to go off of.

Comment: Been trying for last hour but it simply won't load for me (uk) - will keep trying, I totally agree its easier to try with

Comment: Do you want them horizontally or vertically?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney http://bit.ly/128rNfn

Comment: @CanGeliş Fiddle added

Comment: @LloanAlas Fiddle added

Comment: Not working for me D: - But take a look at my demo below ^-^.

Comment: @LloanAlas Added JSBin example

Comment: @LloanAlas Wrong, please read OP

Comment: Yea - sorry - meant to delete all of the above as I didn't understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tend to set a base CSS rule for all images like this to make them automatically act responsively =

```
img {
     width:100%;
     height:auto;
}
```

This way the image retains its aspect ratio based on the parent/container width, setting the height to the correct proportional size when resized.

Comment: Hmm ok - if you can provide an example link I'll take a look and see if there is a conflicting style in the parent container or elsewhere

Comment: Added Fiddle and JSBin examples to play with

Comment: Ah ok, well what you need to do in order for the images to resize but retain the grid layout is apply a div around each image and set some alternating classes, i.e. image one has a class with a width of 40%, image 2 has a class with width 60% - floating these left or `display: inline-block;` should make these 'columns' act responsively, and the images will adjust to their parent div width which will also be resized. - Does that make any sense? I'll do a demo tonight if it would help?

Comment: Thanks, totally get what you mean. Not really worth it in the grand scheme of things as a nightmare to upkeep should i choose to change an image, so going to adopt a different layout. Appreciate the reply.

Comment: No worries! This might be a good method to try at some point utilising jQuery Masonry plugin! http://osvaldas.info/responsive-jquery-masonry-or-pinterest-style-layout

Answer (score 0):

```
#hp_imgs {
    width:66%;
    float:left;
    max-width:143px;
    height:auto;
}

#hp_imgs img {
    float:left;
    margin:2px;
    border-radius:4px;
    display: block;
    max-width:143px;
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: A bit of comment/details? How could OP come to this solution?

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your question.